# Error on iif for color expression

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have this statement in my SSRS report.

```
=iif(
    ((Fields!lngCount2.Value-Fields!lngCount.Value)/Fields!lngCount.Value) > 0
        and Fields!strSegmentName.Value ="Struggler" 
        or Fields!strSegmentName = "Winback" 
        or Fields!strSegmentName.Value = "Former", 
            "Green" , 
                    iif(
                        ((Fields!lngCount2.Value-Fields!lngCount.Value)/Fields!lngCount.Value) < 0 
                            and Fields!strSegmentName.Value ="New" 
                            or Fields!strSegmentName = "Riser" 
                            or Fields!strSegmentName.Value = "High Value", 
                                "Green",
                                    "Red" )
)
```

I'm getting the below error.

> An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of
>   the report 'Main Report' is invalid. The Color expression for the
>   textbox ‘textbox8’ contains an error: [BC30518] Overload resolution
>   failed because no accessible '=' can be called with these arguments:

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

Think you're missing the '.value' on `Fields!strSegmentName = "Riser"` and `or Fields!strSegmentName = "Winback"`